No corta el mar, sino vuela
En los siguientes versos de José de Espronceda, ¿qué significa "no corta el mar"? ¿Podría significar "no dividir el mar"? ¡Muchas gracias!

Con diez cañones por banda,viento en popa a toda vela, no corta el
mar, sino vuelaun velero bergantín:bajel pirata que llaman, por su
bravura, el Temido,en todo mar conocido del uno al otro confín.


Si acudimos al DRAE para consultar el verbo cortar, encontramos


tr. Hender un fluido. Una flecha corta el aire; un buque, el agua.


Si acudimos a ver más detalles sobre hender, tenemos


tr. Atravesar o cortar un fluido. La flecha hiende el aire. El buque hiende el agua.


En resumen, un buque o navio, como el descrito en el poema, se dice que se desplaza a través del agua, a través del mar [atravesar].
corta el mar = hiende el agua = navega
Volviendo al poema, esa frase es una hipérbole donde el autor indica que el Temido se desplaza tan rápidamente que parece no tocar el agua, que vuela. El verbo volar también se emplea en español para indicar que algo se desplaza muy rápido, independientemente del fluido donde se produzca el desplazamiento.

¡Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda!
